# iOS over-the-air ad-hoc app installs with 'intergrity canot be verified'. Install by cable via iTunes works perfectly

Tags: ios, iphone, ad-hoc-distribution, over-the-air

I have an ad-hoc app. I distribute it with manifest.plist file.
When I install it, the app appears on the phone but not working because of Integrity cannot be verified.
UDID is inside the ipa, I extracted it and checked in Notepad.
If I hook up the phone to a pc and install the same ipa by cable from Windows from iTunes - it works like a charm.
No idea where to search for a solution.

Thank you.